# How do you get the link of a video in discord

Tags: python, youtube-dl

So I'm trying to get the URL of a video, using youtube-dl. But cannot find out how to get the URL, using python.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below.

```
@client.command(pass_context = true)
async def play(ctx, url):
 server = ctx.message.server
 voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
 player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
 player.start()
```

Comment: well i use rewrite and i get the video that i need to play by searching youtube with what the user says. I just want to know how to get the link of the video i search up.